# Why is it problematic to configure the database files and the system swap space on same disk?

Tags: mysql, database, swapfile

Why is it problematic to configure the database files and the system swap space on the same disk? What can happen?

Comment: [sf] is possibly a better fit for this question.

Comment: Oh, I never heard about this plattform before. Thank you!